# MVC C# Message read update

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a message inbox system in MVC.

In my website, I will have notification span/label in the nav bar that alerts the user if they have an unread message (similar to this site's notifications on the top). If a user clicks on a message in his inbox that is unread, this will send a call to the database to update that messages column Read to false. How can I update the both the inbox and nav bar to show that I have one less message unread?

Do I go Ajax, javascript and if so what is the easiset way to accomplish this?

Comment: Ajax, [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), [jQuery Realtime](https://github.com/leggetter/jquery.realtime).

Comment: @firecape Please avoid posting answers in the comments. Comments are for asking questions. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Geoff, I just thought it was such a general answer that it didn't really count as an answer :)  I'll post in the answer section even if I think it's too general.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a full postback of course. If you want something more interactive without a full page refresh, then there's a plethora of front-end languages/frameworks out there that can help. One reason front-end clients like Angular and others came to the forefront was because Jquery/Javascript quickly became hard to manage as pages become more interactive. If it's just one small thing you're doing, try JQuery -- if you're going to have lots of areas where the page will need to respond to events, then look into front-end frameworks.

Comment: I'll look into front end frameworks since doing it with jquery is possible but since I am opening a modal to view the message, it would be hard to do a full postback and wouldn't be good in my case. Using jquery would also be quite difficult but sill possible